# How to make search system work in laravel which can run through an array stored as string in database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I wish to make a search box which will run the search query. I have stored my data in database table in this form

> asdf,english class science 5,chapter 1

I wish to use, to seperate between different tags.

I need to search across this. So if the user types chapter1 the search query should be able to pick up the chapter1 in the row. At present the search query is not able to pick anything. My code is as follows:

```
 $tag = $request->search;
    $query = Comics::where('comics_tag','LIKE','%'.$tag.'%')
    ->get();
    var_dump($query);die();
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: `I have stored my data in database table in this form asdf,english class science 5,chapter 1`....and that's your first mistake. Learn about how to structure a relational database properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that instead of storing your tags as a string, you should create a many to many relationships between your comics and your tags, you will be able to easily manage them after :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

then once you have a `tags()` relationship for your comics :

```php
$comics = Comics::whereHas('tags', function($query){
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%" . request()->search . "%");
})->get();
```

As for the naming convention, your Models should be singular, so it should be :

`Comic::class` and not `Comics::class`